# Get mysql last uptime

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I just restarted the MySQL service.

I know how to get the current Uptime, but by any chance is there a way to get the uptime before last restart ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: You might be able to reconstruct this from log file entries regarding MySQL starts and stops ...

Comment: Good idea Sven, log was disabled but I can see it in syslog. Now I just have to crawl 30+ logs files.gz... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost the same problem. I solved it this way:

1) Insert into `my.cnf` this line:

```
init_file = /some-path/startup.sql
```

2) In the file `startup.sql` you have these `MySQL` commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MySqlServerLog ( MySqlServerStarted DATETIME );
INSERT INTO MySqlServerLog SET MySqlServerStarted = NOW();
```

Each time you start/restart the `MySQL` server this script is executed and it logs very simple the exact start time.

The uptime can be then very easy calculated for each start/restart.

Comment: Good tip, will be useful for other things too ! I'm still a bit disappointed that they have no buitin stats or something